# Match Policies using the API

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Can I apply match policies using the API v2 or v3, or is my only option to use the SFTP upload method?

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing public in the Data API v2 or v3 that you could use at this time. If you want, you can follow up with me via email to discuss your use case further—jeffy at google dot com.